# ID movie: memory erased, SF, with sample

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm looking for a movie, SF, the guy has erased his memory himself (the big cliffhanger). He is the boss and wins it all in the end.

Often people are in a conference room, and they are all unconscious but him, but sit and have eyes wide open.

There are some parts of that movie on this video:

1min14 - 1min25
2min35 - 2min54

If you have the name of the actor, I'm interested as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Might this be 2002 film *[Cypher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cypher_(film))* starring [Jeremy Northam](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000562/)?

> Morgan Sullivan (Northam), a recently unemployed accountant, is bored with his suburban life. Pressured by his wife to take a job with her father's company, he instead pursues a position in corporate espionage. Digicorp's Head of Security, Finster (Bennett), inducts Morgan and assigns him a new identity. As Jack Thursby, he is sent to conventions to secretly record presentations and transmit them to headquarters. Sullivan is soon haunted by recurring nightmares and neck pain. When he meets Rita Foster (Liu) from a competing corporation, his life starts to become complicated.
>
> Rita gives him pills to cure his pain and nightmares and tells him not to transmit at the next convention. After the convention, Digicorp confirms the receipt of his transmission, though Morgan had sent nothing. Sure that something strange is going on, Morgan takes the pills Rita gave him and finds that they work. Confused by what is going on, and intrigued by Rita, he arranges to meet with her again. At the meeting, she tells him about Digicorp's deception and offers him an antidote – a green liquid in a large syringe. Morgan hesitantly accepts. She warns him that no matter what happens at the next convention he must not react.
>
> Morgan discovers that all the convention attendees are spies as he is, all thinking themselves individual spies working for Digicorp. While they are drugged from the served drinks, plastic-clad scientists probe, inject and brainwash them....

I believe the convention scene where people are drugged is the source of the clips you provide above. Compare the clips to the scene below:

Indeed, he eventually realizes his true identity of Sebastian Rooks.

Found on the TV Tropes page for [Laser Guided Amnesia](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LaserGuidedAmnesia). I vaguely remembered the plot twist from an earlier search for a short story where the reveal at the end was the protagonist learning he was the mysterious boss he's been pursuing throughout the film.

Comment: You got it right, thank you very much!